# Get Date part from string

Tags: c#

During my code execution

```
                    doc2.LoadHtml(item.InnerHtml);
                   string detail1 = item.InnerHtml.Trim();
                   string head1 = item.InnerText.Trim();
```

I am getting strings in head1 like this

"Commodity Trade Estimate for Oil seed Crop as on 20.10.2011 and Availability of Vegetable Oils" or 
"Commodity & Knitting from  April, 2011" etc

Now I want to put only Date part from that string to insert date automatically related to that post, not manually. Date part in the head1 string may be  like below

```
>"______20.10.2011", 
>"______April, 2011"______, 
>"______Nov. 2008 to Oct. 2009", 
>"___2007-08 (Nov.-Oct.)______"
```

What function or regular expression I used to get only Date part from the strings???

Comment: When you down-vote a question, please provide comments so the questioner can learn how to ask questions more appropriately (I have not down-voted the question, so I have no more specific comment than that).

Comment: what have you tried so far by your side? you better write your tried effort (code) also, so we can tell you better about your mistake.

Comment: Please make your question crisp and understandable. Whether you want date part i.e., (_20 in 20 April 2013, 20-04-2013, 20.04.2013, 20/04/13_). In your questions for inputs like **April,2011**, it is not possible to extract the date part

Answer (score 0):

This will extract, parse and print all dates in the input text:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\b\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}\b");
foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(inputText))
{
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(m.Value, "dd.MM.yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
 }
```

Now, if you just want the first date, you can do that:

```
static DateTime? GetFirstDateFromString(string inputText)
{
var regex = new Regex(@"\b\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}\b");
foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(inputText))
{
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(m.Value, "dd.MM.yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        return dt;
}
return null;
}
```

Note that the method returns a nullable DateTime, so that it can return null when the string contains no date.

Comment: And... `April, 2011` ?

Comment: similarly you can create REGEX(Regular Expression) for that pattern.

Comment: and that's what the question being asked

Comment: If Date part in string is like this "15.11.2013" then dt is return with Date which is part of string but for like "March, 2013" not going inside foreach loop.

Comment: use Regex Coach to create Regular Expression, see if your regular expression is valid or not.
this link might help you ...    http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're dealing only with English, what if you started with this list of strings:

```
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr
May
Jun
Jul
Aug
Sep
Sept
Oct
Nov
Dec
to
```

And searched for the longest substring that contained only:

1. One of those strings
2. Punctuation
3. Digits
4. Spaces

And assume that substring represents the date?

Here's the RegEx. Just pick the longest match that it finds:

```
/\b(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Sept|Oct|Nov|Dec|to|[^A-Za-z])+\b/gi
```